# For what $x$ is it true, for all $y$, that $\sin y + \sin(x-y) =\sin x$?

Tags: trigonometry

> For what value(s) of $x$ is the following true for all $y$?
>   $$\sin y + \sin(x-y) =\sin x$$

I'm not sure how I would solve this.

I tried expanding it 
$$\sin y + \sin x\sin y - \sin y\cos x -\sin x = 0$$

Then $$\sin y(1-\cos x) - \sin x(1-\cos y) = 0$$
But I couldn't do anything after.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If the identity holds for all $y$, then plugging $y=\pi$ gives you the following requirement on $x$:
$$0  + \sin(x-\pi)=\sin x.\tag1$$
Since $\sin(x-\pi)=-\sin x$, this implies that $\sin x =0$, and therefore $x$ must be a multiple of $\pi$.

Plugging $y=\frac\pi2$ gives you
$$1+\sin\left(x-\frac\pi2\right)=\sin x,$$
which simplifies to
$$1-\cos x = \sin x.\tag2$$
Requirement (2) rules out odd multiples of $\pi$, so the only remaining candidates for $x$ are **even multiples of $\pi$**. You can check that the identity does hold for these $x$, in which case the identity simplifies to the true statement
$$\sin y - \sin y = 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
 \sin y+ \sin(x-y) &= 2\sin\left(\frac{y+x-y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{y-(x-y)}{2}\right)\\
 &= \sin x = 2\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}
 \end{align*}
    and hence
    \begin{align*}
  \sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{2y-x}{2}\right)
 &= \sin\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}\\
 \sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\left(\cos\left(\frac{2y-x}{2}\right) -\cos\frac{x}{2} \right) &= 0\\
 \sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\times 2\sin\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)\sin\frac{x-y}{2} &= 0
 \end{align*}
    Since this is true for all $y$, we must have $x = 2n\pi$.

Another way to see this:

Since the relation is true for all $y$, differentiating with respect to $y$, we get 
\begin{align*}
\cos y - \cos(x-y) = 0
\end{align*}
and hence 
\begin{align*}
2\sin \frac{x}{2}\sin\frac{x-2y}{2} = 0
\end{align*}
and hence $\sin\dfrac{x}{2} = 0$ and $x = 2n\pi$.